# Generate a list of symbols for the planets

Tags: curated-data, astronomy, built-in-symbols

I would like to generate a list of the symbols for the planets to include in a nice table with other data. How can I programmatically generate (eg. using a pure function) the symbols from a list of the planets' names as strings.

Such an input list is generated as follows:

```
AstronomicalData["Planet"]
```

> {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"}

If I can do it for one name, then it's solved. Doing it manually by typing `\[Saturn]` produces the desired symbol `♄`, but doing it manually is not a desirable option.

The following attempt fails in any case:

```
\[#] & /@ {"Saturn"}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
ToExpression["\\[" <> # <> "]"] & /@ {"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", 
  "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"}
```

Gives

[image]

(also corrected the code thanks to Kuba)

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively:

```
CommonName[EntityClass["Planet", All]["Glyph"]]
```

or just

```
EntityClass["Planet", All]["Glyph"]
```

if you don't mind the Entity formatting.

Comment: You can also do `EntityValue[EntityClass["Planet", All]["Glyph"], "Name"]`.

Comment: @ChipHurst Good call!  Or even `Through[EntityClass["Planet", All]["Glyph"]["Name"]]`